# Not enough space to yum install in a rhel7 ubi podman container

Tags: rhel7, podman, buildah

I am trying to install multiple pkgs to build a jenkins agent container off of a rhel7 ubi. I keep running into a 'not enough disk space' error during the yum install steps while building the image. I know podman uses overlayfs which I thought is elastic to storage needs. Can any one offer some insight on how to expand available container storage?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fuse-overlay?  Versus vfs driver.  I would suspect you are running with vfs and this is using up a lot of disk space in your homedir.

Questions like this would be better on github or in bugzilla.